# C#>Label edited with jquery ignore HTML tags

Tags: c#, jquery

For some reason when i insert html in a label using jquery the label consider the tags as normal text

ex:

- i want this -> **ABC**
- label show this -> < b >ABC < /b >

When btnBold is pressed it takes txtA's value, change it to bold, then give this value to LabelB

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {

      function ChangeText(elementID, openTag, closeTag, elementID2)
      {
         var textArea = $('#' + elementID);
         var textArea2 = $('#' + elementID2);
         $(textArea2).text("<b>" + textArea.val() + "</b>");
      }

    $('#btnBold').click(function () {
       ChangeText("<%=txtA.ClientID%>","<b>","</b>","<%=LabelB.ClientID%>");
   });
```

ASPX

```
<button id='btnBold' value='Bold' style="width:20px;"><b>n</b></button>    
<asp:textbox id="txtA" Text="ABC" tabIndex="1" runat="server" ></asp:textbox>
<asp:Label ID="LabelB" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: What behaviour are you getting and if there is an error what is it and where does it occur?

Comment: The code actually works, but my label consider html tags as simple text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use html() instead:

```
$(textArea2).html("<b>" + textArea.val() + "</b>");
```

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative 1:**

```
$(textArea2).css("font-weight","Bold").text(textArea.val());
```

**Alternative 2:**

```
<style type="text/css">
 .bold {font-weight:bold;}
</style>

<script> 
  $(textArea2).addClass(bold).text(textArea.val());
</script>
```

Comment: I will try your solution, seems to be a good idea too, Thank you

Comment: No problem. I hope this helps.